# Magento2: Product created from front-end is not adding to cart,it results "We can't add this item to your shopping cart right now."

Tags: magento2, addtocart, create-product

However the sample products are adding in cart,this is problem with products that has been added programmatically. Below is the code I am using to create the product programmatically.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
        $product = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
        $product->setSku($productData['sku']); 
        $product->setAttributeSetId(9);
        $product->setCreatedAt(strtotime('now'));
        $product->setName($productData['productname']);
        $product->setWebsiteIds(array(1));          
        $product->setDescription($productData['productdesc']); 
        $product->setShortDescription($productData['short_description']); 
        $product->setAttributeSetId(4); 
        $product->setStatus(1); 
        $product->setWeight($productData['productweight']); 
        $product->setVisibility(4); 
        $product->setTaxClassId($productData['tax_class_id']);
        $product->setTypeId('simple'); 
        $product->setPrice($productData['price']); 
        $product->setSpecialPrice($productData['special_price']);
        $product->setSellerId($productData['sellerId']);
        $product->setCategoryIds($productData['categories']);
        $product->setStockData(
                    array(
                        'use_config_manage_stock' => 0,
                        'manage_stock' => 1,
                        'is_in_stock' => $isInStock,
                        'qty' => $quantity
                    )
                );

        $product->save();   </i>
```

Comment: Please check `var\log` for error

Comment: You have passed `setAttributeSetId` **2** times. remove it one.

Comment: Yes I have removed one but the issue still persist.

Comment: @AnkitShah Nothing is coming in error log

Comment: HI guys! this is solved, actually there is an observer which called with add cart process and there is some error in it.That is why it was not working.
Thanks!!

Comment: Can you share in detail how you fix it please as I am getting this same error.

Answer (score 0):

This below code will create a product with -sample sku of existing SKU and add product to the cart.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
        try {
            $product->setWebsiteIds(array(1)) //website ID the product is assigned to, as an array
                    ->setAttributeSetId(4) //ID of a attribute set named 'default'
                    ->setTypeId('simple') 
                    ->setCreatedAt(strtotime('now')) 
                    ->setSku('sam'.$sku) //SKU
                    ->setName($name."-sample")
                    ->setWeight(4.0000)
                    ->setCategoryIds(7)
                    ->setStatus(1) 
                    ->setTaxClassId(4) //tax class (0 - none, 1 - default, 2 - taxable, 4 - shipping)
                    ->setVisibility(1) 
                    ->setPrice(0.99) 
                    ->setMetaTitle($prod->getMetaTitle())
                    ->setMetaKeyword($prod->getMetaKeyword())
                    ->setMetaDescription($prod->getMetaDescription())
                    ->setDescription($prod->getDescription())
                    ->setShortDescription($prod->getShortDescription())
                    ->setMediaGallery (array('images'=>array (), 'values'=>array ())) 
                    ->addImageToMediaGallery($imageUrl, array('image','thumbnail','small_image'), false, false)
                    ->setStockData(
                        array(
                           'use_config_manage_stock' => 0, //'Use config settings' checkbox
                           'manage_stock'=>1, //manage stock
                           'min_sale_qty'=>1, //Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
                           'max_sale_qty'=>2, //Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
                           'is_in_stock' => 1, //Stock Availability
                           'qty' => 99999 //qty
                        )
                    );

                //echo "BEFORE SAVING THE NEW PRODUCT";
                $res = $product->save();
                //echo "AFTER SAVING THE NEW PRODUCT";

                //var_dump($res); 
                $ids=$product->getEntityId();
                // Save the new Sample Product ID to original product Attribute. 
            } catch (Exception $e ) {
                echo    $e->getMessage();
            }
        $cart = $objectManager->get('Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');
        $productRepo = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository');
        $pId=$product->getId();
        $productData = [];
        $productData['qty'] = 1; 
        $productData['product'] = $pId; 

        $_addproduct = $productRepo->getById($pId);
        if ($_addproduct) {
            $cart->addProduct($_addproduct, $productData); // adds product in cart using cart model
        }
        $cart->save();
        $cart->getQuote()->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false)->collectTotals();
        $cart->getQuote()->save();
```